# Tortoise how to view changes before commit using WinMerge?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, winmerge

Is it possible to see file changes with previous version using Winmerge before commit?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course.

Right click on a folder or file under version control, and choose `Tortoise SVN->Settings` from the pop-up menu.

Navigate to the `External Programs->Diff Viewer` item in the treeview on the left. Check the radio button for `External` in the `Configure the program used for comparing different revisions of files` at the top, and put in the information for WinMerge. See the `TortoiseSVN Help file` (click the `Help` button at the bottom right of the mentioned dialog) for command-line options (including the exact ones needed for WinMerge).

Comment: Ken is exactly correctly and one should use the suggested WinMerge parameters given on the help page. Just wanted to point out, though, that TortoiseSVN is smart enough to still work even if you omit all the parameters (i.e. just use the path to the WinMerge executable). It is less friendly, though; those switches make a better user experience.